# How do I save my screen GNU session?

Tags: ssh, gnu-screen

I am trying to use a GNU screen session to go through a long code line by line to debug. I'm working in it through a shell. I start the screen with `screen -S Name`. Normally I run a few lines of computation and those take a while so I leave terminal open. Sometimes the pipe breaks to my ssh so I close out terminal. When I come back a few hours later and try `screen -r Name`, the screen is gone and doesn't show up with `screen -ls`. Was it deleted? How can I stop this from happening? I can't progress with my work because I keep losing it

Comment: What SSH client are you using? Are you connecting from a Windows client? Another Linux machine? The GNU session is on a Linux machine, not running on Cygwin on a Windows setup?

Comment: I'm using a mac terminal that is connecting to a ssh in Chicago, I think the other computer is linux

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly sure that **most** ssh clients log out of the server when they disconnect/log out/lose connection - in which case, the server drops all the processes that user had running in the active ssh Window. One solution you could try is to do `nohup screen -S name`, which will run the command but will accept no keyboard input and will not output to the console - instead outputting the console to a `nohup.out` file in the folder where you run the command. Some commands, however, don't run under `nohup`, so you may be out of luck running the command through `nohup`, although I have been able to run commands that don't work by calling a `*.sh` script through nohup. Hope this helps.

Comment: How do I run a big code then? I want to run an Rscript line by line interactively to debug but my Mac can't handle it. And some of the lines take too long in my ssh that I get logged out? My boss said to use screen

Comment: personally, I've never had experience with `screen`, so I'm not too sure. The `nohup` command outputs to a file, so couldn't you just go back and look through that? I'm just telling you a method that works for me with other applications that close when I exit the ssh console (one prime culprit is the minecraft/craftbukkit server).

Comment: can `nohup` interactively run R and let me look at data.frames to analyze where my errors are

Comment: nohup cannot run interactively, it accepts no keyboard input when it's running